# Path Spawner stops working after a few minutes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a endless runner (something like Temple Run) as my first ever game in unity. I wrote this code which runs when the player passes a trigger collider. It moves the pathway behind the camera and moves it infront of the player.

```
public List<GameObject> paths;
public float offset = 50;


// Removes Path behind the Camera or Player and moves it infront.  
public void movePath()
{
    GameObject movePath = paths[0];
    paths.Remove(movePath);
    float newZPos = paths[paths.Count - 1].transform.position.z + offset;
    movePath.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, newZPos);
    paths.Add(movePath);

}
```

This runs perfectly fine for a few minutes but then break.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I started leaning C# 3 weeks ago as my first programming language so I don't know a lot of advance stuff.

Comment: How do you define "stops working"? Does it no longer spawn anything? Does it get very slow? Does it spawn new things, but they seem out of place? We can't see what you're seeing, so you'll have to help us.

Comment: I have tried playing it a few time. On the first run after a few minutes it didn't spawn anything. On the second run it spawned very slowly.

This also happens if I increase my Player speed.